# Ruby on Rails + pickadate.js -> what's wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pickadate

I'm beginner in RoR and trying to enable pickadate.js in my app.

In matching controller's file `app/assets/javascripts/calc_date.js.coffee`
I've typed:

```
$ ->
  $(".date").pickadate()
```

In form partial `app/views/calc_date/_form.html.haml` I've typed:

```
= form_tag('/calc_date/calc') do
  %div
    %b Please, select date:
    = date_field_tag 'date', @date, id: "date", class: "date"
    = submit_tag 'Calculate'
```

When I click into input field nothing is happening.
I'm expecting that a calendar widget will appear but it won't work.

In application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require pickadate/picker
//= require pickadate/picker.date
//= require pickadate/translations/ru_RU
//= require_tree .
```

In application.css:

```
*= require pickadate/default
*= require pickadate/default.date
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

I did a try with jquery-ui-date and it worked. I use the same way with pickadate.js but got no reaction from it.

In terminal window I can see lines like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/pickadate/picker.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-12 15:26:44 +0300

Started GET "/assets/pickadate/picker.date.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-12 15:26:44 +0300
```

What is my mistake or what had I've missed?

Thank you.

Comment: Open Browser Developer Tools and check JS errors in console.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You've opened my eyes. But what to do with them?

Comment: These are: `TypeError: document.body is null`, `ReferenceError: Picker is not defined`, `TypeError: jQuery.fn.pickadate is undefined`, `TypeError: $(...).pickadate is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old but I just came across a similar issue and I think it would be the same problem you seem to be having.

Bit of a run down for my situation:
I'm working on a client's form and have pickadate running, it was working, then I realized that every time I loaded a new page it wouldn't initiate... refresh page, works again.

What was the problem...... TURBO LINKS.... my god, that thing drives me nuts. I always take it out but it was in there as I can see its in your app too.

Apart from that, your code seems fine, should be working.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails asset pipeline ignores the first folder in the `assets` directory. Try this instead:

In application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require picker
//= require picker.date
//= require translations/ru_RU
//= require_tree .
```

In application.css:

```
*= require default
*= require default.date
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```